# KEYEXPIRED error while apt-get update and there is no expired key in apt-key list

Tags: apt

I got error while `sudo apt-get update`

```
Err:6 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease
  The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1507181400
```

According to [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/615362), expired key are shown by `apt-key list`.

```
$ LANG=C apt-key list | grep expired
$
```

But it is not shown by the command.

What should I do to fix this error?
I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS.

Comment: I do see the expired keys in the list printed by `apt-key`.

Comment: Whoever coming from search: check this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/598344/debian-8-jessie-keyexpired-1587841717

Answer (score 10):

To solve the problem I just needed to get new key by following command.
I couldn't find out why the key isn't recognized expired in `apt-key list`, though.

```
curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

Comment: For me, this source for a new key worked instead: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/655336/22947